# How to detect when a item is added to or removed from a ListView in UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

There doesn't seem to be an event for detecting when an item is added or removed from a ListView... VERY strange, when it seems to be something that would be commonly used by a developer... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

if the ItemSource of your ListView is bound to an **ObservableCollection** then you can easily get notified when an item is added or removed to the collection ( which results in same change in your ListView as well ).

**XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyCollection}"/>
```

**Backend**

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> people {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

and then you can subscribe to [OnCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.oncollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1_OnCollectionChanged_System_Collections_Specialized_NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs_) event of the this collection like :

```
people.OnCollectionChanged += (s,e) => {//you logic goes here}
```

> More on how to bind an ObservableCollection to a ListView : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32820.uwp-binding-observeable-collection-to-listview-control.aspx